# Updating a data.table either works or doesn't work depending on the column names given

Tags: r, data.table

Well, I'm feeling a bit stupid here. I'm clearly missing something, but I can't figure out what.
Depending on the column names I give when initializing and updating a data.table, it either works or doesn't work:

```
library('data.table')
n.rows <- 2L
dx <- 10L
dy <- 10L

dt1 <- data.table(dx = integer(n.rows), dy = integer(n.rows))
dt1[1, c('dx', 'dy') := list(dx, dy)]
```

This doesn't update row number 1, in fact it seems to do nothing (no warnings):

```
> dt1
   dx dy
1:  0  0
2:  0  0
```

**After changing the column names from 'dx' and 'dy' to 'val.dx' and 'val.dy, however, it works as intended:**

```
dt2 <- data.table(val.dx = integer(n.rows), val.dy = integer(n.rows))
dt2[1, c('val.dx', 'val.dy') := list(dx, dy)]

> dt2
   val.dx val.dy
1:     10     10
2:      0      0
```

What's going on? I also tried with=FALSE, but - as expected from ?set - that wasn't successfull. Are there some limits on the column names allowed that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is about scoping. The scope of the `j`-expression is *within* the `data.table` itself, so when you wrote `list(dx, dy)` that's the same as writing `list(dt1$dx, dt1$dy)`, which is why you're getting those results.

If you insist on having same names, you can use `eval` to evaluate the variables in the global scope:

```
dt1[1, c('dx', 'dy') := list(eval(dx, .GlobalEnv), eval(dy, .GlobalEnv))]
dt1
#   dx dy
#1: 10 10
#2:  0  0
```